# rails4 custom routes to serve static pages mapped in a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hy,
i have a resource called static_pages.
Is possible to configure routes to have somethings like this:

```
www.example.com/about ==> static_pages#show
```

I think is difficult becouse the show action expected an id passed via params.

have any idea?

Comment: Are you going to render `show` without passed params? Then there'll be some errors. But if you're talking just about how to route `/about` to `#show`, then in `routes.db` you should write (if you want GET request) `get '/about', to: 'static_pages#show'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just add this route:

```
get 'about', to: 'static_pages#show'
```

More info on routing is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: thanks, if i use yours solutions my service is not restfull. So, i possible to mantain bouth the routes ? Example: www.example.com/about render correct page. www.example.com/static_pages/11 render the correct page. is possible?

Comment: This doesn't make it not RESTful -- it just matches that route to `show` for static pages like you asked. You can also put `resources :static_pages` in your routes to use both. Generally, `show` should take an ID to identify a resource, so I would recommend creating a new method in the `static_pages` controller for the `about` page.